# Typescript & rxJS group list of object by month/year and map to certain value

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have class:

```
export class DayValue {
  date: string;
  status: string;
}
```

and statusToPointsMap:

```
  public static map: Map<string, number> = new Map([
    ['COMPLETED', 100],
    ['FAILED', -100],
    ['SKIPPED', 0],
  ]);
```

I want to create function which calculates avg result per given period of time, ie:

```
[
  [
    "2020-05-02",
    "COMPLETED"
  ],
  [
    "2020-05-01",
    "FAILED"
  ],
  [
    "2020-04-30",
    "FAILED"
  ],
  [
    "2020-04-29",
    "SKIPPED"
  ],
  [
    "2020-03-13",
    "SKIPPED"
  ]
]
```

to (groupped by month)

```
[ ["05-2020",0],
  [ "04-2020",-40],
  ["03-2020",0]
```

]

or(groupped by year):

```
["2020",-16]
```

I created a function which works as I wanted, but I'm wonder if there is any way to to it smarter?

```
  private calculateAvgPerPeriod(values: DayValue[], period: string): any[] {
    const resultArray = [];
    from(values).pipe(
      groupBy(dayValue => this.datePipe.transform(dayValue.date, period)),
      mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())),
      map(array => [
          this.datePipe.transform(array[0].date, period),
          array
            .map(day => this.statusToPointsMap.get(day.status))
            .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0) / array.length
        ]
      ))
      .subscribe(entry => {
        resultArray.push(entry);
      });
    return resultArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using RxJS, but your inputs and outputs are plain arrays. It'd be simpler to either consume and return streams or replace RxJS with Lodash/Ramda/Underscore/native array methods/some iteration-based library.

(If you want to get really fancy or need to use the function in different contexts, you could write a [transducer](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#transduce).)

You're using a class, a method and a static property, but it would be sufficient to have a type, a function and a module-local constant. And passing `datePipe` (or just a `Date`) and `status => getPointsFromStatusToPointsMap(status)` function as arguments would make the dependencies more explicit. But these are more like code style preferences.

Lastly, you're returning `any`, but you should always return `unknown` instead unless you really have to lie to the type system for some reason. And returning `[string, number]` or `[Date, number]` would be more convenient for the consumer.